# How to write it pretty?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, copy

Hi i am new in c# and i want to ask how to write this code more prety

```
public void Update(Product pr)
    {
        Product prod = GeProductById(pr.ProductID);
        prod.Name       = pr.Name;
        prod.Count      = pr.Count;
        prod.InputPrice = pr.InputPrice;
        prod.InputDate  = pr.InputDate;
        prod.OutPrice   = pr.OutPrice;
        prod.InputPriceByCurrency   = pr.InputPriceByCurrency;
        prod.InputPriceCurrency     = pr.InputPriceCurrency;
        prod.ComeOwner  = pr.ComeOwner;
        prod.GroupID    = pr.GroupID;
        prod.Discount   = pr.Discount;

        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

All it do just copy all properties except id. Can i write it shortly?
Thanx and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What's wrong with it? Seems perfectly readable, aside from odd tabbing and names. It can be better if you can save `pr` directly. Are you using a framework here?

Comment: @Kobi Yeah ) but what if it will be 10 or 20 properties )) I want write it shortly. Thanx for response

Comment: Well then you would do it through reflection, but I would not suggest doing that...

Comment: @Nazar Gargol thanx i will keep it in my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there's more to this.  Why can't you save `pr` to the data store as is?  It seems like you may be using the ORM inefficiently, though there could be good reason for this that we just can't see from the scope of this code.

On a more general note, you may have luck with something like [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) in cases like this.  Though, honestly, I think with a little re-working of how you're using the ORM it shouldn't be necessary here.

Based on comments to far, I'd also like to note that there's nothing inherently wrong with a long and boring mapping function like this.  Even if it's 20 properties or 200 properties.  If it's only written once, is easy to read and understand what it's doing, does what it's doing well, etc. then it's not a bad piece of code.  Code isn't always pretty, and it doesn't need to be.  It's easy to be tempted to do something more clever to make the code cooler or more interesting, but clever isn't always better when it comes to supporting that code later.

Comment: I here that i must change object that i get from bd when update SubmitChanges? How can i just store it and submit? dont get it (((

Comment: @Sanja Melnichuk: This is mostly speculation based on what I see in the code presented, but it seems like you should be retrieving the object from the data store before you do whatever is done prior to this method being called (change its properties elsewhere in the application, etc.) and then save it back to the data store.  Rather than create a new object that represents one in the data store and map it just before update, as you seem to be doing here.

Comment: Thanx for response now i fill better )

Answer (score 4):

As David said before you are probably using the ORM the wrong way.

Maybe this article explaining [updates in Linq-To-Sql](http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/) could be of help

Basically you can call the Attach method to attach the outer entity to the current context and SubmitChanges later turning off optimistic concurrency